# Grails Command Object validation for input list

Tags: grails, grails-orm, command-objects

Hi how do I set the command object constraint nullable, blank, and custom for these 2 list, event[] and qty[] from the below html?

```
<div class="row-1">
    <select name="event[]" class="form-control ">
        <option selected="">abc</option>
        <option selected="">def</option>
    </select>
    <input name="qty[]" >
</div>
<div class="row-2">
    <select name="event[]" class="form-control ">
        <option selected="">ghi</option>
        <option selected="">jkl</option>
    </select>
    <input name="qty[]" >
</div>


class someCommand implements Validateable {

    List eventComponent
    List qty

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hi how do I set the command object constraint nullable, blank, and
>   custom for these 2 list

You could do something like this:

```
class someCommand implements Validateable {

    List eventComponent
    List qty

    static constraints = {
        eventComponent nullable: false, validator: { theList ->
            // return true if theList is valid
            // return false or a message code if theList is invalid
        }
        qty nullable: false
    }
}
```

You wouldn't use `blank` for a `List`.  `blank` is for validating `String` properties.  If you want to make sure the list has elements in it, you could use `minSize: 1`.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I think you are going to have separate issues because of the way your markup is constructed, but the above answers the question about how to set constraints for those properties.